# In Germany, is there a reward for reporting possible tax fraudsters or money launderers to the authorities?

Tags: criminal-law, tax-law, germany, currency, money-laundering

I could well be wrong and I don't want to go into specifics here, but...

Let's assume I know of a business that in reality generates a few hundred thousand euros in revenue and yet shows a P+L with revenue far in excess of those numbers. This could imply they are laundering money — paying some tax just to get the money into circulation.

1. Who would I report this suspicion to?
2. If I were proven right, would there be a reward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can report your suspicions to any German police station or any prosecution service (Staatsanwaltschaft). Furthermore, in this case to any tax authority (Finanzamt). Your report may be made anonymous. You will not get a reward.